# Retrieve count of the result set and other columns in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query does an inner join on `contents` and `tag` tables. (using mysql)

```
            SELECT
                contents.original_duration,
                tag.tagconfig,
                contents.id_contents
            FROM
                contents
                    inner JOIN
                tag
                    ON
                contents.id_contents = tag.id_contents
                AND contents.id_host = tag.id_host
                AND contents.id_vhost = tag.id_vhost

            WHERE
                tag.video_insert_status='idle'
                AND contents.type = 'video'
                AND contents.subtype = 'video'
                AND original_duration is not NULL;
```

`id_contents`, `id_host` and `id_vhost` are the primary keys in bot `tag` and `contents` table. The above query results 260 results.

How can I select this count in a single query?

I tried

```
SELECT
                contents.original_duration,
                tag.tagconfig,
                contents.id_contents,
                count(contents.original_duration)
```

but, it doesn't seem to give the correct result.

Comment: Do you want the result as a new column, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is to `GROUP BY` all columns in your select list, and then use `COUNT(*)` to get the number of records:

```
SELECT
    contents.original_duration,
    tag.tagconfig,
    contents.id_contents,
    COUNT(*) AS recordCount
FROM
    contents
        inner JOIN
    tag
        ON
    contents.id_contents = tag.id_contents
    AND contents.id_host = tag.id_host
    AND contents.id_vhost = tag.id_vhost
WHERE
    tag.video_insert_status='idle'
    AND contents.type = 'video'
    AND contents.subtype = 'video'
    AND original_duration is not NULL;
GROUP BY
    contents.original_duration,
    tag.tagconfig,
    contents.id_contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the SELECT clause of the original query with

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

will give the count.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two same query and join them to get what you want, like:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.CNT
FROM (
    SELECT
        contents.original_duration,
        tag.tagconfig,
        contents.id_contents
    FROM
        contents
            inner JOIN
        tag
            ON
        contents.id_contents = tag.id_contents
        AND contents.id_host = tag.id_host
        AND contents.id_vhost = tag.id_vhost

    WHERE
        tag.video_insert_status='idle'
        AND contents.type = 'video'
        AND contents.subtype = 'video'
        AND original_duration is not NULL) T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM
        contents
            inner JOIN
        tag
            ON
        contents.id_contents = tag.id_contents
        AND contents.id_host = tag.id_host
        AND contents.id_vhost = tag.id_vhost

    WHERE
        tag.video_insert_status='idle'
        AND contents.type = 'video'
        AND contents.subtype = 'video'
        AND original_duration is not NULL
) T2
```

Or you can execute following sql, and you can get count by the last record:

```
SELECT
    contents.original_duration,
    tag.tagconfig,
    contents.id_contents,
    @CNT := @CNT + 1 AS CNT
FROM
    contents
        inner JOIN
    tag
        ON
    contents.id_contents = tag.id_contents
    AND contents.id_host = tag.id_host
    AND contents.id_vhost = tag.id_vhost
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @CNT := 0) T
WHERE
    tag.video_insert_status='idle'
    AND contents.type = 'video'
    AND contents.subtype = 'video'
    AND original_duration is not NULL
ORDER BY CNT
```